# Loop through List & Merge Rows then add Heading

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

New to Loops but know general VBA. Im struggling to get a macro to work how I need it. It currently does operate but I know there is a better way to do it, and without some of the errors I get so hoping you can educate me and make it better for its purpose !

I have a data table that comes in raw format and varies in size, I organise that into 'States' I then need the Macro to find the first instance of a state from column D, insert a new row then merge the row and add that word as the heading.

Example before the code:
[BEFORE RUNNING CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpnBO.png)

Example after running Code:
[AFTER RUNNING CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvWEP.png)

I often get a debug error for some of the States as sometimes the data doesn't have that particular state on it, i tried to add the On Error GoTo but it doesn't seem to go to the next one it just errors and ends.

Ideally i want the the macro to keep looping through all the states in column D to add a heading until it reaches the end. The states can be different on each data pull.

Thanks for any help or advice. I know this probably looks a mess but its the best I could write and google wasn't bringing anything up. Hope i have explained what I need.

This is the code I have been using so far.

```
Sub InsertRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rang As String
Dim Text2Find
Dim CopyTextRng As String
Dim Text As String

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Call FormatTable
'-------------------------------
On Error GoTo Err1

Text2Find = "Break"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err1:
On Error GoTo Err2
Text2Find = "Meal"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err2:
On Error GoTo Err3
Text2Find = "ManualSetACWPeriod"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err3:
On Error GoTo Err4
Text2Find = "OutboundCallResearch"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err4:
On Error GoTo Err5
Text2Find = "SystemFault"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err5:
On Error GoTo Err6
Text2Find = "ManagersDiscretion"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err6:
On Error GoTo Err7
Text2Find = "BuzzSession"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err7:
On Error GoTo Err8
Text2Find = "Coaching"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err8:
On Error GoTo Err9
Text2Find = "TeamMeeting"
Cells.Find(What:=Text2Find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Call Merge

Err9:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

'--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Sub Merge()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(Val(1) - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert

rang = "A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & "G" & ActiveCell.Row
Range(rang).Merge

Range(rang).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    
CopyTextRng = "D" & ActiveCell.Row + 1
Text = UCase(Range(CopyTextRng).Value)

Range(rang) = Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking all the `Text2Find` names and integrating it into a variable that we can loop through you can reduce the amount of code used.

While looping through the names, I am checking to make sure the name is found in `column D`, if it is it will call the `Merge sub`

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRow()

Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Put your sheetname in here

Dim lCtr As Long
Dim arrLookup As Variant
Dim lngRowFound As Long

'Add all statuses in here
arrLookup = Array("Break", "Meal", "ManualSetACWPeriod", "SystemFault", "ManagersDiscretion", "BuzzSession", "Coaching", "TeamMeeting")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select ' Do not bneed to activate sheet as it is declares above
Call FormatTable

'Loop through names
For lCtr = 0 To UBound(arrLookup)

    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(arrLookup(lCtr), oWS.Range("D:D"), 0)) Then 'Check to see if name is valid
        Call Merge(oWS, arrLookup(lCtr))
    End If

Next lCtr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

'-------------------------

```
Sub Merge(oWS As Worksheet, strLookup As Variant)
Dim lngRowInsrt As Long: lngRowInsrt = Application.Match(strLookup, oWS.Range("D:D"), 0)
Dim rng As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Insert new row and shift cells down
oWS.Rows(lngRowInsrt).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Set rng = oWS.Range("A" & lngRowInsrt & ":" & "G" & lngRowInsrt)

With rng
    .Value = strLookup
    .Merge                          'Merge cells
    .Font.Bold = True               'Bold Font
    .Interior.Color = vbYellow      'Color it yellow
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .BorderAround , xlThin
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That's amazing ! Thanks so much does exactly what I need !
Just to further my knowledge, if i wanted the array to contain a list from another sheet, is this possible? Or would I have to just keep adding them to the macro code?

Thanks again !

Comment: You could build a loop to gather the list from another sheet or assign it to a `range` and `loop` through the range